# Trim whitespace while comparing strings - sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have query like

```
Select *
From ReportData L 
Left Join ATM A On L.ATMID=A.ATM 
Where L.ATMID=A.ATM AND L.IssuerNetwork < > '0000'
```

it retrieve result only when `ATMID` & `ATM` is like `'TWAW1800           '` & `'TWAW1800           '` But FAILS when `'TWAW1800'` & `'TWAW1800           '`

What i Tried is

```
Select *
From ReportData L 
Left Join ATM A On L.ATMID=A.ATM 
Where LTRIM(RTRIM(L.ATMID))=LTRIM(RTRIM(A.ATM)) AND L.IssuerNetwork < > '0000'
```

But it doesnt work for me..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Place the `LTRIM()/RTRIM()` on the `JOIN` so then it strips the whitespace when joining:

```
SELECT *
FROM ReportData L 
LEFT JOIN ATM A 
  ON LTRIM(RTRIM(L.ATMID))=LTRIM(RTRIM(A.ATM))
WHERE L.IssuerNetwork <> '0000'
```

Answer (score 3):

Try putting the LTRIM in the ON clause, not the WHERE clause. Where happens after the join, which already throws away the differing matches due to spaces.

As an aside, I think some DBs treat trailing spaces as not actually there. Just FYI.

Comment: Hah. Always ten seconds too slow :)